# 02180. 00000 - "invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I want to create a TABLESPACE with this command

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "COMMDATA" DATAFILE
  'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\TELEFONICA\COMMDATA01.ORA' SIZE 32G AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1073741824 MAXSIZE 32G,
  'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\TELEFONICA\COMMDATA02.ORA' SIZE 32G AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1073741824 MAXSIZE 32G
  LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192
  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT
 NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
   ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE
  'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\TELEFONICA\COMMDATA01.ORA' RESIZE 32G
```

but I got this error:

```
2180. 00000 - "invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a semicolon missing at the end of the `NOCOMPRESS SEGMENT ...` line, isn't it? ALTER DATABASE can't be part of the CREATE TABLESPACE.